# Does filter in AngularJs work if value = 0?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have `$scope.event.privacy = 0;`

When I'm trying todo `{{ event.privacy | eventPrivacyFilter }}` filter doesn't do anythink... But if `$scope.event.privacy = 1 or 2 or .....` it's work.

Does filter in `AngularJs` work if `value = 0`?

Filter:

```
 (function() {
    'use strict';


    angular.module('eventMod').filter('eventPrivacyFilter', eventPrivacyFilter);


    function eventPrivacyFilter(EventPrivacyRegistry) {
        return function(privacyId) {
            if (!privacyId) {return null;}
            return EventPrivacyRegistry.getById(privacyId).name;
        };
    }
})();
```

Regist:

```
    (function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('eventMod').service('EventPrivacyRegistry', EventPrivacyRegistry);

    function EventPrivacyRegistry(_) {

        return {

            getList: function () {
                return [
                    { id: 0, name: '1'},
                    { id: 1, name: '2'},
                    { id: 2, name: '3'},
                    { id: 3, name: '4'}
                ];
            },

            getById: function (privacyId) {
                console.log(privacyId);
                console.log(_.find(this.getList(), {id: privacyId }));
                return _.find(this.getList(), {id: privacyId });
            }
        };

    }
})();
```

Comment: show the filter code.

Comment: Please put some more code here. We can't see anything.

Comment: @TarunDugar look to updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if (!privacyId) {return null;}` is the statement which returns null when `$scope.event.privacy = 0` because `if(!0)` evaluates to true.

And therefore, `EventPrivacyRegistry.getById(privacyId).name;` is not executed in this case.

The solution would be to compare with `null` and `undefined` as follows:

```
if(privacyId === null || privacyId === undefined) {
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with AngularJs. This is javascript `falsy value`.

Zero (0) is evaluated to falsy value in your example.
If want to strict comparison then you need to explicitly ask for it.

So change your code like this

```
// old code
{{ event.privacy | eventPrivacyFilter }}

// new code
{{ event.privacy != null | eventPrivacyFilter }}
```

Read more about comparing falsy and truthy values here http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/